# C++ console application; time optimised queue in a dental clinic situation

Tags: c++, queue, console-application

I'm trying to solve a queue problem that is required in my assignment.

The details are as follows : 
- I am asked to create an automate robust queuing sub-system (note that the each dental clinic has 2 doctors and 4 dentist chairs, 1 x-ray machine on its premise)
- Time-optimised algorithm (different type of treatment). For example, tooth decay would require 30 minutes, checkup would be only 15 minutes, etc.
- Every clinic expected about ~20 and ~15 patients in the morning and afternoon per day respectively.
- The clinic timing is 8am – 12pm, 2pm – 6pm

Upon asking my lecturer, he said that I would need 2 queues(for each doctor), x-ray machines would be an instant process and requires no time at all and in the end of the day, when comparing these 2 queues, the difference of the total duration would be almost equal.

I have been trying to solve this problem but to no avail. Can someone explain how these would be solved?

EDIT :

I have created the queue implementation and a Visit class that is supposed to be enqueued into the queue. What I need to figure out is the algorithm on how to schedule all these visits such that the queues will be time-efficient.

Visit.h

```
#ifndef Visit_H
#define Visit_H

#include "MC.h"
#include "Doctor.h"
#include "Assistant.h"
#include "Condition.h"
#include "Medicine.h"
#include "Treatment.h"

class Visit
{
private:
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
    double duration;
    Staff staff;
    MC mc;
    bool xRayStatus;
    List<Treatment> treatmentList;
    List<Condition> conditionList;
    List<Medicine> medicineList;
public:
    Visit();
    Visit(std::string, std::string, double);
    std::string getDate();
    void addStaff(Staff);
    Staff getStaff();
    void setMC(MC);
    MC getMC();
    void addXRay();
    bool getXRayStatus();
    void addCondition(Condition c);
    void addMedicine(Medicine m);
    void addTreatment(Treatment t);
    List<Treatment> getTreatmentList();
    List<Medicine> getMedicineList();
    List<Condition> getConditionList();
};
#endif
```

Visit.cpp

```
#ifndef Visit_CPP
#define Visit_CPP

#include "Visit.h"

Visit::Visit()
{

}

Visit::Visit(std::string d, std::string t,  double dur)
{
    date = d;
    time = t;
    duration = dur;
}

std::string Visit::getDate()
{
    return date;
}

void Visit::addStaff(Staff s)
{
    staff = s;
}

Staff Visit::getStaff()
{
    return staff;
}

void Visit::setMC(MC m)
{
    mc = m;
}

MC Visit::getMC()
{
    return mc;
}

void Visit::addXRay()
{
    xRayStatus = true;
}

bool Visit::getXRayStatus()
{
    return xRayStatus;
};


void Visit::addCondition(Condition c)
{
    conditionList.add(c);
}

void Visit::addMedicine(Medicine m)
{
    medicineList.add(m);
}

void Visit::addTreatment(Treatment t)
{
    treatmentList.add(t);
}

List<Treatment> Visit::getTreatmentList()
{
    return treatmentList;
}

List<Medicine> Visit::getMedicineList()
{
    return medicineList;
}

List<Condition> Visit::getConditionList()
{
    return conditionList;
};

#endif
```

Queue.h

```
//Queue.h - - Specification of Queue ADT (implemented using Pointers)

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include "Visit.h"
using namespace std;

typedef Visit ItemType;

class Queue
{
  private:
    struct Node
    {
      ItemType item;    // item
      Node     *next;   // pointer pointing to next item
    };

Node *frontNode;    // point to the first item
Node *backNode; // point to the first item


  public:
    // constructor
    Queue();
    //destructor
    ~Queue();


    // check if the queue is empty
    bool isEmpty();

    // enqueue item at the back of queue
    bool enqueue(ItemType& newItem);

    // dequeue item from front of queue
    bool dequeue();

          // dequeue and retrieve item from front of queue
    bool dequeue(ItemType& item);


    // retrieve item from front of queue
    void getFront(ItemType& item); 





};
```

Queue.cpp

```
/** @file Queue.cpp */

#include <cstddef>   // for NULL
#include <iostream>
#include <new>       // for bad_alloc
#include "Queue.h"  // header file

using namespace std;

Queue::Queue()
{
    backNode = NULL;
    frontNode = NULL;
}  // end default constructor


Queue::~Queue()
{
   while (!isEmpty())
      dequeue();
}  // end destructor

bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
   return backNode == NULL;
}  // end isEmpty

bool Queue::enqueue(ItemType& item)
{
     // create a new node
      Node *newNode = new Node;
      newNode->item = item;
      newNode->next = NULL;

      // insert the new node
      if (isEmpty())
     // insertion into empty queue
         frontNode = newNode;
      else
     // insertion into nonempty queue
         backNode->next = newNode;

      backNode = newNode;  // new node is at back
      return true;
}  // end enqueue

bool Queue::dequeue() 
{
   if(!isEmpty())
   {  // queue is not empty; remove front
      Node *temp = frontNode;
      if (frontNode == backNode)   // special case?
      {  // yes, one node in queue
         frontNode = NULL;
         backNode = NULL;
      }
      else
         frontNode = frontNode->next;

      temp->next = NULL;  
      delete temp;
      temp = NULL;
      return true;
   }  // end if
   else 
   {
       cout << "empty queue, cannot dequeue" << endl;
       return false;
   }

}  // end dequeue

bool Queue::dequeue(ItemType& item)
{
   if (!isEmpty())
   {  // queue is not empty; retrieve front
      item = frontNode->item;
      dequeue();  // delete front
      return true;
   }  // end if
   else 
   {
       cout << "empty queue, cannot dequeue" << endl;
       return false;
   }

}  // end dequeue

void Queue::getFront(ItemType& item)
{
   if (!isEmpty())
      // queue is not empty; retrieve front
      item = frontNode->item;
    else 
        cout << "empty queue, cannot getFront" << endl;
}  // end getFront

// End of implementation file.
```

Comment: The hardest and most important part in any software project is understanding the requirements.  I think you still need to work on this part before you start coding.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? It's hard to help if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I am having trouble with the implementation of the algorithm that is needed in the main.cpp. I have done and included the Visit class and Queue data structure above. The requirements are understood completely, however the assignment writeup is written very vaguely and my classmates are having a hard time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of the assignment as an event driven system.
One queue would contain events that need to be handled.

If we have an event class like so:

```
struct Event  
{  
  virtual bool  execute_if_time(const Time& t) = 0;
};
```

We could have a `vector` of pointers to events:

```
typedef std::vector< boost::smart_ptr<Event> > Event_Container;
Event_Container events;
```

There would be a scheduler loop:

```
while (1)
{
  Time t = now();
  for (Event_Container::iterator iter = events.begin();
       iter != events.end();
       ++it)
  {
     (*iter)->exeute_if_time(t);
  }
  sleep(/* some duration */)
}
```

The scheduler would execute events in the container at periodic intervals.

Note:  this is only one scheme, as there are many others that would suffice.

The rest of the code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: So in my case, how would this be implemented? I'm sorry as I am a newbie in C++

Comment: The above code is an implementation.  You really need to consult with your instructor.